# Dealing with accents in the URL

Tags: php

I have sent the following to a url query string "Filosofía" and it appears as "?page=filosofía" in the browser. Which is great. But when I read it from the $_REQUEST variable and convert it back into an htmlentities string it converts to "filosofÃ­a" which is not what is expected which is "Filosofía" what it originally was.

What do I do to get this converted correctly so that I can do comparisons.

I tried comparing "filosofía" with what came back originaly i.e. "filosofía" and it failed.

- So confused, need help!

Comment: Using non-ASCII characters literally in a URL will almost always break something (there are others who will try and tell you otherwise, but they are wrong, frankly). You should always [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) anything that will be used directly in a URL, to avoid any possible room for ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You could use utf8_encode and utf8_decode functions along with urlencode

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are always using utf-8 everywhere: PHP file, Apache config, mysql connect, ...

Force utf-8 for your page by setting a header:

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8', true);
```